# eager loading is returning related object as null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Good day, I am using entity framework database first, with asp.Net MVC. You can see my model here

```
 public class Respuesta
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public Detalle Detalle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Detalle")]
    public Guid DetalleId { get; set; }
    public int Orden { get; set; }
}

   public class Detalle
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Describir { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoProyecto TipoProyecto { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TipoProyecto")]
    public Guid TipoProyectoId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Ejemplo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 Orden { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string DescripcionProfesional { get; set; }

}
```

When I execute the following query, the "Detalle" object is returning as null but the other fields are coming with data.

```
var answers= _dbContext.Respuesta.Where(r => r.DetalleId == DetalleId).ToList();
```

[image: the problem]

This is the schema

[image: db schema]

I am thinking it is strange, since in the past while doing the same, I never received objects as null.

What is going on? thanks

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but try adding `[Key]` to the `Id` fields.

Comment: I will try it thanks

Comment: what is the table schema looks like? esp. the foreign key column names?

Comment: Use `Include()`.

Comment: @GertArnold It seems I needed to use incluse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after researching a little about the Include() method, per Gert Arnold answer, 
this is the query I use:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

_dbContext.Respuesta.Include(r=>r.detalle).Where(r => r.DetalleId == DetalleId).ToList();
```